# how to attach a listener to my DroidGap?

Tags: android, cordova, listener

I use technology DroidGap in my source

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

}
}
```

**Activity** is not used, after "super.loadUrl (super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");" I totally use the web

**I want... no matter what the web page is now open, when I click on the screen, start this listener **

```
View.OnClickListener activityLauncher = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        }
    };
```

please help.

Comment: you want that event in native code or in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one external javascript file, write following code in it:

```
<script>
document.getElementByTagName("body").addEventListener('touchstart',touchPagePressed);// you can use 'onclick' also
function touchPagePressed()
{
   MyAndroid.performClick();
   alert(touchPagePressed');
}
</script>
```

include that external js file in every html page.

after this, write following code in your onCreate method:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
             {
                public void performClick()
                {
                   // Deal with a click on the body tag
                }
             },"MyAndroid");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(e);

        return true;
    }
```